# Trouble Scraping a Page Full of JavaScript Code Using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

I am currently working on a web scraping project using Python and Selenium, and I'm encountering difficulties with a particular webpage that seems to be heavily reliant on JavaScript. When I inspect the page source, I can't find any HTML code to search within. Consequently, when I use the find_element method in Selenium, it raises a NoSuchElementException.

I have attempted various approaches, including trying different attributes such as CSS selectors and class names, but none have been successful in locating the elements I need.

`browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome().install()) browser.get('https://my.te.eg/user/login') browser.find_element(By.ID,"login-service-number-et")`

i tried use mechanicalsoup library and also deosnt work, howver when i inscpect an element in a page it show me the html code, but when i open 'opent page source' it is full of java script code and the webdriver object always get the javascript code

Comment: Did you wait until the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the page not fully loading when you're searching for the element which causes the NoSuchElementException, You'll have to wait till that resource is visible, have a look at webdriver wait but essentially for example:

```
  # creates a waiting object with the amount of time it should wait before returning and error message
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
    
#this essentially says wait till the element to be located is visible i.e if you're waiting on a button to load, it'll wait till its visible before whatever you want to do
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

Thats just a high level view but expected conditions has different use cases for what you'd like to do

Documentation on wait stratergies : https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/